# How to find out how many TCP retransmits are occurring?

Tags: networking, tcp

I am running Debian Wheezy on an ARMHF platform and do most of the communications over fairly unreliable cell phone networks.  Is there a way to read the no. of re-transmits the TCP stack has done since booting?  Also keeping track of the no. of TCP checksum failures would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to regularly check those numbers (or even log them somewhere), maybe `netstat` can help as explained here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/318909/how-passively-monitor-for-tcp-packet-loss-linux

You could log the output and analyze it later.

If you need something to watch in realtime, perhaps [tcptrace](http://www.tcptrace.org/) fits the bill.

An alternative could be to use plain old [tcpdump](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=wheezy&arch=armhf&searchon=names&keywords=tcpdump) to dump your traffic and then use some more involved analysis tool on your own workstation to analyze it, like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

`tcpdump`, `netstat` and `tcptrace` all exist for Debian wheezy on armhf.

Answer (score 4):

If you install and enable the "sysstat" package and enable SNMP for sadc. You can then get TCP retransmit information using the below command. And you will also have a configurable amount of historical data (below output is from Ubuntu 13.10).

```
# sar -n ETCP
Linux 3.11.0-12-generic (hamilton)  2014-10-14  _x86_64_    (2 CPU)

16:05:01     atmptf/s  estres/s retrans/s isegerr/s   orsts/s
16:15:01         0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00
Average:         0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00
```